# How can I define a number parameter for this own align environment?

Tags: align, optional-arguments

I'm "trying to change the "0.5" as needed.
It would be perfect if this command could have an default value of 0.5.

Unfortunately it seems to be very difficult to create a new environment with the "align"-environment.

```
\def\blockbegin#1\blockend{
\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
\begin{align*} #1
\end{align*}
\end{varwidth}~\hfill}
```

---

Edit: I'm still not happy because there are some recurring things I'd like to automate.
Here is my application. It's simply displaying math homework in two columns.

How can I move the right box up /align vertically at the top?

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth}

\newenvironment{block}[1][0.5]
{\varwidth{#1\textwidth} \csname align*\endcsname}
{\endalign\endvarwidth \hfill}

\newcommand{\void}{\vspace{3ex}
\rule[0cm]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\}

\begin{document}

2.b) Berechnen Sie die Fläche, die der Graph von $f$ mit der x-Achse im I. Quadranten einschließt.\\ \\
This is how it's done:\\ % can I include the `\\` in the FIRST ’block’-command
\begin{block}
 A(u) &= \int_{0}^{u} (f(x)) \cdot dx\\
 &= \int_{0}^{u} (3xe^{-x}) \cdot dx\\
 &= \Big[-3(x+1)e^{-x} \Big]_{0}^{u}\\
 &= \Big(-3(u+1)e^{-u} \Big) - \Big(-3(0+1)e^{-0} \Big)\\
 &= \Big( \frac{-3(u+1)}{e^u}  \Big) - \Big(-3 \cdot 1 \Big)\\
 &= \frac{-3(u+1)}{e^u} + 3 
 \end{block}
 \begin{block}
 A =& \lim\limits_{u \to \infty} \Big(A(u)\Big)\\
 =& \lim\limits_{u \to \infty} \Big(\frac{-3(u+1)}{e^u} + 3 \Big)\\ \\
 =& 3
\end{block}
\void % Can I include this at the end of the last ’block’

Here it goes..

\end{document}
```

### [image]

I thought about it and this is the construct is what I'm actually using:

```
\newcommand{\exsection}[3]
{
 #1:\\
 \begin{block}
  #2
 \end{block}
 \hfill
 \begin{block}
  #3
 \end{block}
 \void
}
here it goes..
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/69818)  Usually we do not use greetings or thanks in our questions: this may look unpolite, at first, but it is part of the style of the site.  The main concern, here, is to provide *concise* an effective information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the purpose for this, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth}

\newenvironment{block}[1][0.5]
 {\varwidth{#1\textwidth}\csname align*\endcsname}
 {\endalign\endvarwidth}

\begin{document}

\fbox{xxx
\begin{block}[.25]
a & b\\
c & d
\end{block}
}

\fbox{xxx
\begin{block}[.5]
a & b\\
c & d
\end{block}
}

\fbox{xxx
\begin{block}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{block}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, only the OP knows why (s)he insisted on using an argument delimited by `\blockend`…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti “Unfortunately it seems to be very difficult to create a new environment with the `align` environment.” It isn't. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Yes! It seems difficult but your answer works just fine ;)

Comment: @JoelDuscha: the key is to avoid using constructs like `\begin{FOO}` and `\end{FOO}` buried *inside* your definition, but to use only the “non-environmental” forms `\FOO` and `\endFOO`.  For an explanation of why this is necessary (and sufficient), see `amsmath.pdf`, section 16.3 (type `texdoc amsmath.pdf` at the command line).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?  EDITED to make the width argument optional, and default to 0.5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,amsmath}
\newcommand\blockbegin[1][0.5]{\def\VWid{#1}\blockbeginX}
\def\blockbeginX#1\blockend{
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\VWid\textwidth} 
\begin{align*} #1
\end{align*}
\end{varwidth}~\hfill}
\begin{document}

xxx

\blockbegin
a & b\\
c & d
\blockend

xxx

\blockbegin[0.25]
a & b\\
c & d
\blockend

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped at least for my uses. What I was trying to say with ’optional argument’ was that it would be optimal for \VWid to have a default value like it is now.

Comment: @JoelDuscha Please see my improved revision that provides the optional argument, with default.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it’s no big deal to make it work with an optional argument too; for example, using `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \blockbegin { O{0.5} u{\blockend} }
  {
    \begin{varwidth}[t]{#1\textwidth} 
      \begin{align*}#2\end{align*}
    \end{varwidth}~\hfill
  }



\begin{document}

xxx

\blockbegin[.5]
a & b\\
c & d
\blockend

xxx

\blockbegin[.25]
a & b\\
c & d
\blockend

xxx

\blockbegin
a & b\\
c & d
\blockend

\end{document}
```

A hand-crafted, pure-LaTeX2e implementation is also possible, of course.

Comment: This looks like a more professional solution. But I'm afraid I do not understand everything of it. Where exactly is the xparse part used? For example I don't understand that whole \NewDocumentCommand line.

Comment: @JoelDuscha: *That’s* exactly the part that uses `xparse`. (;-)  But, really, why don’t you use an environment, as egreg suggests, instead of a delimited argument?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical TeX-like implementation that provides an optional argument for `\blockbegin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\blockbegin{\@ifnextchar[\blockbegin@i{\blockbegin@i[0.5]}}
\def\blockbegin@i[#1]#2\blockend{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{#1\textwidth} 
    \begin{align*} #2
    \end{align*}
  \end{varwidth}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

xxx

\blockbegin
  a & b\\
  c & d
\blockend

xxx

\blockbegin[.25]
  a & b\\
  c & d
\blockend

\end{document}
```

Comment: *Exactly* what I had in mind when I spoke of “pure LaTeX2e implementation”. :-)

Comment: So, is this preferable because it is a “pure LaTeX2e implementation” ? Or should I use xparse?

Comment: @JoelDuscha: The solution I would recommend is egreg’s, unless you have a specific reason to use `\blockend` as the argument delimiter (for instance, compatibility with legacy code); in this case, use Werner’s answer or mine, whichever you understand better.  **Edit:** I wrote my answer only to honor your request for a delimited argument.

Comment: @JoelDuscha: That's really up to you. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides a modern implementation of the macro specification (and is used with most LaTeX3 implementations). However, if you understand the LaTeX2e and TeX constructions like `\@ifnextchar`, then that works fine as well.